# How do I pass the arguments from a text file to run a program under gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb, xargs, shellcode

I want to use the function like the command under gdb.

```
$ cat arg.txt | xargs ./binary
```

Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks and I got an simple solution.

```
(gdb) run $( cat arg.txt )
```

It is also possible to pass the output of a command to be the arguments.

```
(gdb) run $( ruby -e 'print( "text as arguments" )' )
```

Comment: `(gdb) run $(cat change_me_bytes.hex)` worked greated for injecting bytes into `argv[1]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When gdb is invoked via `xargs` it's stdin by default is redirected from `/dev/null`. Obviously gdb needs stdin to read and perform user input but it can't because stdin is `/dev/null`.

One way to solve this issue is to use `xargs` with `--arg-file`:

```
xargs --arg-file arg.txt gdb --args ./binary
```

See [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
   -a file, --arg-file=file
          Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use
          this option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are run.
          Otherwise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.
```

Comment: This solution handles other xargs situations, such as when args are delimited with nul bytes rather than line terminations.